# How to find an element in ng-repeat using foreach with protractor?

Tags: javascript, foreach, protractor

I have list of `ng-repeat` in my angular page. Each repeater has five different items on it.

I want to search for a value in all the repeater's list and then find the matching item from the list.

```
function(callback){
    browser.sleep(2000);
    element(by.css("h1 > span.ng-binding")).getText().then(function(text) {
        var myid = text.trim();                    
        console.log("****text"+text);
    });

    element(by.id("categories")).click();
    element(by.linkText("kids")).click();
    browser.sleep(6000);
    var Content = element(by.css("[slides=\"ctrl.requestsHtml\"]"));
    var tableRepeater = Content.all(by.repeater("view in ctrl.views track by $index")).each(function(rowElem,index){
        var myRowElem = rowElem;
        rowElem.element(by.tagName("div")).getOuterHtml().then(
            function(success){
                console.log(success);
                //if this repeater row has the myid we are looking for, click the Edit button
                if(success.match(/myid/)!=null){
                    var Edit = rowElem.element(by.linkText("Edit"));
                    Edit.click();
                }
            }

        )

    });
    callback();
}
```

Comment: Please add your code and ask question. we can't answer without your code.

Comment: @Dinesh , Please see my code , when I run this code ..I am getting the following error message.                                                                       
      Failed: rowElem.element(...).getOuterHtml is not a function

Answer (score 2):

> rowElem.element(...).getOuterHtml is not a function

`getOuterHtml()` method *was removed from the API* - use `getAttribute()` instead:

```
rowElem.element(by.tagName("div")).getAttribute("outerHtml");
```

---

I also think that you actually need to use [`.filter()`](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.filter) and not `.each()` in this case:

```
var desiredRow = Content.all(by.repeater("view in ctrl.views")).filter(function(rowElem) {
    return rowElem.element(by.tagName("div")).getAttribute("outerHtml").then(function(outerHtml) {
        return outerHtml.match(/myid/) != null;
    });
}).first();

desiredRow.element(by.linkText("Edit")).click();
```

Also note how I've removed the "track by" part from the "by repeater" locator - it is not needed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However I used ur code and it returns the following error.                                                                                 
TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of null.                                             I want to clarify one thing here.  i am using the condition to check the element "myid " exists or not ,if exists then click the Edit button.

Comment: @James could you post the complete traceback showing where does it fail and how? Thanks.

Comment: Hi Alex, Please see the code below. I have changed little bit. It is grabbing the array but when i put condition , it is not returning the value that matched the condition.

Comment: <!--var desiredRow = element.all(by.repeater("view in ctrl.view track by $index")).filter(function(rowElem) {
                    return rowElem.getText().then(function(outerHtml) {
                        console.log("print outerHtml"+outerHtml);
                        //console.log("print id"+id)
                        return outerHtml == id;
                    });
                }).first();      -->